# How can I quickly lookup country and US state by lat/lng?

Tags: node.js, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I don't want to take the time to do an http request. Ideally there would be a node package that just had a list of state and country border outlines and told me which outline my lat/lng was in?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-geocoder

Comment: afaict only supports external lookups

Comment: did you search google for "open data us map" or something similar ? I've found 2 links that may help you so far: http://www.data.gov/open-gov/ and http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/504. BTW, you may search or post your question in GIS StackEchange website (http://gis.stackexchange.com/) which is dedicated to this kind of question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This module: https://github.com/vkurchatkin/which-country doest exactly that for countries. You can provide different `.geo.json` file to make it work for US states